# Here I am trying to simplify it to reduce duplication (Common pattern)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

All of these if conditions in the below method have similar pattern, Any ideas to come up with a common method to reduce the duplication in this method?

some case we want all the version, and in some case we want only specific version.

I tried with switch case.

```
public override Func<JObject, dynamic, string> VersionMethod => (jobject, parameters) =>{
        bool hasValidObject = false;

        if (jobject["swVersion"] != null)
        {
            _livetv.SoftwareVersion = new VersionInfo(jobject["swVersion"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["hwVersion"] != null)
        {
            _livetv.HardwareVersion = new VersionInfo(jobject["hwVersion"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["ltvVersion"] != null)
        {
            _livetv.LTV2Version = new VersionInfo(jobject["ltvVersion"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["ltv3Version"] != null)
        {
            _livetv.LTV3Version = new VersionInfo(jobject["ltv3Version"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["cricVersion"] != null)
        {
            _livetv.KAVersion = new VersionInfo(jobject["cricVersion"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (jobject["bbVersion"] != null)
        {
            _livetv.BasebandVersion = new VersionInfo(jobject["bbVersion"].Value<string>());
            hasValidObject = true;
        }

        if (hasValidObject)
        {
            return GenerateSuccessful();
        }

        return GenerateUnsuccessful(
            "Unable to parse version from request, try again.");
    };
```

Comment: It may be a better idea to post this to the Code Review stack exchange, you may get a better response over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like:

```
private VersionInfo GetVersionInfo(JToken token)
{
    if (token != null)
        return new VersionInfo(token.Value<string>());
    else
        return null;
}


public override Func<JObject, dynamic, string> VersionMethod => (jobject, parameters) => 
{
    bool hasValidObject = false;

    hasValidObject |= (_livetv.SoftwareVersion = GetVersionInfo(jobject["swVersion"])) != null;
    hasValidObject |= (_livetv.HardwareVersion = GetVersionInfo(jobject["hwVersion"])) != null;
    hasValidObject |= (_livetv.LTV2Version = GetVersionInfo(jobject["ltvVersion"])) != null;
    hasValidObject |= (_livetv.LTV3Version = GetVersionInfo(jobject["ltv3Version"])) != null;

    // <<<snip>>>

     if (hasValidObject)
         return GenerateSuccessful();
     else
         return GenerateUnsuccessful(
            "Unable to parse version from request, try again.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a method like this one:

```
    public VersionInfo GetVersionInfo(JObject jobject, string jObjectField, ref bool found)
    {
        if(jobject[jObjectField] != null)
        {
            _livetv.SoftwareVersion = new VersionInfo(jobject[jObjectField].Value<string>());
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then call it like this:

```
    public Func<JObject, dynamic, string> VersionMethod = (jobject, parameters) =>
    {
        bool hasValidObject = false;

         _livetv.SoftwareVersion = GetVersionInfo(jobject, "swVersion", ref hasValidObject);
         _livetv.HardwareVersion = GetVersionInfo(jobject, "hwVersion", ref hasValidObject); 
         _livetv.LTV2Version = GetVersionInfo(jobject, "ltvVersion", ref hasValidObject);
         _livetv.LTV3Version = GetVersionInfo(jobject, "ltv3Version", ref hasValidObject); 
         _ivetv.KAVersion = GetVersionInfo(jobject, "cricVersion", ref hasValidObject);  
         _livetv.BasebandVersion = GetVersionInfo(jobject, "bbVersion", ref hasValidObject); 

        if (hasValidObject)
        {
            return GenerateSuccessful();
        }

        return GenerateUnsuccessful(
            "Unable to parse version from request, try again.");
    };
```